# Can you determine if a destination is a queue or topic at runtime?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, jms-topic

I have interesting challenge of having to publish a message to a Topic in one environment and having to send a message to a Queue in another one. Both the environments needs to have the same code base. Is there any way to determine at run time if the target is a queue or a topic and invoke code to send to topic or queue accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Queue and Topic extend Destination. So if you have an instance of Destination you can use `instanceof` to determine if it's a Queue or a Topic

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is, I do not know if destination X is a queue or a topic. Would I be able to create a destination object for X and then check if it is queue or topic and invoke code accordingly? Will appreciate your further thought.

Comment: Session object has two methods #createTopic(String) and #createQueue(String). So, in general, using only standard JMS the ansnwer is no. You should know the type of destination in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering the question, it's necessary to first ask what, exactly, you believe the code would do differently for a queue versus a topic?  If the WMQ classes are less than a decade old, they use the unified model available since JMS 1.1.  Rather than picking between a `queueConnectionFactory` vs. a `topicConnectionFactory`, have the code instantiate a generic `connectionFactory`.  Rather than instantiating a `queue` or `topic` object, have the code instantiate a `destination` object.  At that point you really do not care whether the thing under the destination is a queue or a topic.

Please see [IBM WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0](http://ibm.co/c6jlIW) for a complete description, including sample code source that shows how it's done.